# Token based credit card systems vs. traditional gateway

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card, braintree

I'm trying to decide between [Paypal PayFlow](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_gateway_payflowpro) for a transaction processing service or a service like [BrainTree](http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/).

BrainTree's service intrigues me because they will actually return a token to you for a credit card which can be used in future transactions. This token acts like a GUID for the credit card, but is useless if stolen. BrainTree is the only service I have come across that uses such a system - but I'm not sure if they are unique or not.

I heard some praise for BrainTree on a recent podcast, and had not heard of them before.

I wondered if anyone has any general advice on picking between the two - from the perspective of how much programming I will need to do or [PCI](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/) concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm based in Europe, and it sounds like you're based in the US?  That being so I can only mention that there are certainly service providers on this side of the pond (and I imagine that one too) that offer pretty decent tokenised payment solutions. Tokenisation is fast becoming the standard way for payment service providers (PSP's) to help merchants with their PCI compliance.

If you want to take advantage of a token solution to help with PCI compliance then its inevitable that you'll end up redirecting users to a third party site. Most PSP's allow the payment page to be styled, to look as close to your source site as possible. The redirecting is necessary to ensure that your source site has no involvement at all with the capture and transmission of card number data. It also means you dont have to worry about integration with Verified By Visa, or MasterCard SecureCode.

Once the third party site has completed the transaction you'll be left with a token value, and again - different PSP's allow different things, but I know some here allow for (eg) card capture only, or authorisation only (allowing settlement to take place at a later time).

Comment: Braintree ( http://bit.ly/braintree ) allows you to process credit cards without capturing or transmitting credit card numbers and without redirecting your users to a third party site. You retain total control of the look, feel, and flow of the checkbox process. To do this, you build a form on your site that submits directly to Braintree. More info at http://bit.ly/braintree-api . Disclosure: I work for Braintree.

Answer (score 1):

PayFlowPro will allow you to do this as well. Checkout the DoReferenceTransaction method of their docs. [Here is a forum post](http://www.pdncommunity.com/pdn/board/message?board.id=nvp&message.id=2348) with some additional info.

Comment: The link you provided is broken

Comment: See page 40 of the [Payflow Pro Developer guide](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CC4QFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcms.paypal.com%2Fcms_content%2FUS%2Fen_US%2Ffiles%2Fdeveloper%2FPP_PayflowPro_Guide.pdf&ei=lSQVTpW1LI7XiALNg8T8Dg&usg=AFQjCNE0fGpggNbesnLcvFDq-PqR-6bBIw&sig2=c3EG0QBqEqpt3yr2REEL5A)

Answer (score 1):

Authorize.NET also supports this through their [Customer Information Manager (CIM) API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/cim/). Speficially look at Page 28 of the [CIM XML guide (PDF)](http://www.authorize.net/support/CIM_XML_guide.pdf). The `<extraOptions>` tag contains the transaction key:

```
<extraOptions><![CDATA[x_customer_ip=100.0.0.1&x_authentication_ 
indicator=5&x_cardholder_authentication_value=uq3wDbqt8A26rfANAA 
AAAP]]></extraOptions>
```

Comment: this is actually the system we adopted. i thought i'd updated this question, but that must've been a different similar question. been very happy with their service - except for the problem (common to many systems of this type) that we dont have full credit card numbers to call the bank with when problems arise

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Amazon Flexible Payment Service? Same low rate as PayPal, but you get the very well done Amazon checkout experience (which as I'm sure you know let's you reuse credit cards and addresses without having to re-enter them for every order.)

You also have the advantage that most people have done business with Amazon before and are comfortable doing it again.

Comment: I dont want to put people on a third party site (except paypal). i had thought about it but i'm actually not especially impressed by the Amazon UI. we're trying to optimize conversion rate by minimizing number of steps and amazon actually has quite a lot of steps for new customers. i'm not sure quite how the experience is for existing customers. i'll check it out again though

Comment: @Simon_Weaver: Yeah I actually hate the Amazon checkout experience. Argh. eBay (combined with PayPal) is currently the easiest one I've come across.